Using CONCAT function in Java ComboBox problem
I'm currently developing a Car Rental System (just for fun and practice) and my problem is when I choose a car in my "Add Transaction" feature, it should be adding the transaction to the selected item, but the selected item is queried using the CONCAT  function.
`private void updateCombo(){
    try{
    String sql = "SELECT CONCAT(carplate,' ',carbrand,' ',carname,' ',yrmodel) AS concated FROM cars WHERE idusers='"+CarRental.ID+"'";
    
    Connector.pstmt = Connector.con.prepareStatement(sql);
    Connector.rs = Connector.pstmt.executeQuery(); 
    
    while(Connector.rs.next()){
        DBcar.addItem(Connector.rs.getString("concated"));
        // Used Concated so since you cannot manually concatinate
        // The columns here
    }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }`

and this updateCombo() function is stored on the class constructor, I'm wondering what I can do so that what car the user chooses to input all this information can be selected properly using the ActionPerformed of the comboBox. Here's a preview of the "Add Transaction" feature of my system
The only thing that makes sense to me is I remove the CONCAT and just simply add the car plate so that it'd be easier to code but it would look better and easier if the user could just see the model along with it.
Here's how I'm gonna use the "Submit" Button, can you guys give me an idea what I can do here?
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
        try{
        dateRented = TFdaterented.getText();
        dateReturned = TFdatereturned.getText();
        payment = Double.parseDouble(TFpayment.getText());
        expense = Double.parseDouble(TFexpense.getText());
        pickUp = TFpu.getText();
        dropOff = TFdo.getText();
        customerName = TFcustname.getText();
        customerNum = TFcustnum.getText();
        
        String sql = "INSERT INTO transactions"+CarRental.ID+" VALUES(NULL, "+CarRental.ID+", ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)";
        Connector.pstmt = Connector.con.prepareStatement(sql);
        Connector.pstmt.setString(1, dateRented); 
        Connector.pstmt.setString(2, dateReturned); 
        Connector.pstmt.setDouble(3, payment);
        Connector.pstmt.setDouble(4, expense);
        Connector.pstmt.setString(5, pickUp);
        Connector.pstmt.setString(6, dropOff); 
        Connector.pstmt.setString(7, customerName); 
        Connector.pstmt.setString(8, customerNum);
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

P.S. I am a beginner

create a Car class/record to hold all data and put instances of that into the model of the JComboBox (kind of an Object Oriented approach)

And don't use 'global' variables like that for your db objects. Make them local variables and handle them with try-with-resources. As user85421 says, have a Car class. You can store an ID in that too (which you don't need to show to the user). Don't use db functions unless you really have to. Although that one is widespread, you never know when a function you've used will not be available in another db you've been forced to port to. Use PreparedStatement::setString too as your code will be cleaner and safe from injection attacks

String sql = "INSERT INTO transactions"+CarRental.ID+" Please tell me you're not creating a separate table for transactions relating to each car...

What's an alternative rather than creating a table for each user? I am very sorry for my poor coding, I am a beginner and am learning on my own.

I can't answer that with precision without knowing your business domain. One 'transaction' table will be enough but not with that exact name as it's already used in db language. USER_TRANSACTION maybe?
